# how to apply row file for specific conditon

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, c#-2.0

I am trying to show grid.I am trying to apply row filter in such a way when my ID=0.
Dont show the row with 0 id in grid view.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Contact.xml"));
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = 0";
    gvfilltempContactus.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    gvfilltempContactus.DataBind();

}
```

I am not able to understand how do i apply not equal to sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID <> 0";
```

You can check it here for [RowFilter Tutorials](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.Select:

```
var strExpr = "ID = 0";
```

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.

```
foundRows = ds.Table[0].Select(strExpr);
```

Or you can use DataView:

```
 ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = strExpr;
```

Or you can do like below.

```
var dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = strExpr;
var newDS = new DataSet();
var newDT = dv.ToTable();
newDS.Tables.Add(newDT);
```